# Google reader api mark an item as Unread

Tags: gdata, gdata-api, google-reader

With the first one url I can mark a post as read but the second one doesn't work. Is this the correct request to mark an item as unread?

```
//THIS ONE WORKS AND I CAN MARK MY ITEM AS READ
NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/edit-tag?a=user/-/state/com.google/read&i=%@&T=%@", entry.identifier, token];

//THIS ONE DOESN'T WORKS AND I CAN'T MARK MY ITEM AS UN-READ
NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/edit-tag?a=user/-/state/com.google/kept-unread&i=%@&T=%@", entry.identifier, token];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to adding the `kept-unread` tag, you also need to remove the `read` one (with the `r` parameter). The request would look like:

```
NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/edit-tag?a=user/-/state/com.google/kept-unread&r=user/-/state/com.google/read&i=%@&T=%@", entry.identifier, token];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you also tell me how can I check the status of an article(for example if it was marked as starred or unstarred, marked as read o unread)?

Comment: How are you getting the entry data? It will have a tags/categories section that lists the read/starred/etc. tags if that item is read/starred/etc.

Comment: P.S. Please accept the answer if it was what you were looking for.

Comment: mmm my question is if exists a query(like to mark a post ad read) to get the status of a post for example if it was marked as read, unread or starred.